# Handle network fail while copying files in C#

Tags: c#, networking, data-integrity

I am writing a C# app that copy files over a network, the problem is that the size of the files and folders to copy is more than 1 TB.
My method is as follows

```
public static void SubmitDocsToRepository(string p_FilePaths) 
{
   IEnumerable<(string,string)> directoryLevels = GetAllFolders(p_FilePaths);
   IEnumerable<(string,string)> filesLevels = GetAllFiles(p_FilePaths);

   foreach (var tuple in directoryLevels) 
       Folder copy logic
   foreach (var tuple in filesLevels) 
       File copy logic                     
}
```

Which would work fine, but assuming something would happen to the network or remote server or the electric power gets lost for whatever reason what should I add to this code to allow me to continue where I left off, especially how could I retrace my steps to where I was.

Comment: Maybe [BITS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bits/background-intelligent-transfer-service-portal) is what you're looking for "to download files from or upload files to HTTP web servers and SMB file shares ... BITS also handles network interuptions, pausing and automatically resuming transfers, even after a reboot"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be something like this:

```
public static void SubmitDocsToRepository(string p_FilePaths)
{
    IEnumerable<(string, string)> directoryLevels = GetAllFolders(p_FilePaths);
    IEnumerable<(string, string)> filesLevels = GetAllFiles(p_FilePaths);

    foreach (var tuple in directoryLevels)
        while (!CopyDirectory(tuple)) ;

    foreach (var tuple in filesLevels)
        while (!CopyFile(tuple)) ;
}

static bool CopyDirectory((string, string)tuple)
{
    try
    {
        // Copy logic
    } 
    catch 
    { 
        // Some logging here
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

static bool CopyFile((string, string) tuple)
{
    try
    {
        // Copy logic
    }
    catch
    {
        // Some logging here
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please could you suggest about the logic that would allow me to continue where I left off?

Comment: The `while(!CopyDirectory(tuple))` will continue with the same directory when it fails.

Comment: I assumed the program will be constantly running until the problems have been resolved. If you need to restart the application than this code will not help you. In that case you would have to test for existence of the directory and skip those directories. For files you would have to check several things for the skip. 1) Does the file exist? 2) Is the size the same? If 1 and 2 are true, skip the file.

Comment: Upvoted but I assume it will be run again from start.